# How to change juju bootstrap time from the 10min it gives you

Tags: juju, maas

When I try to boostrap, I get this after 10 mins. The node that it is trying to bootstrap comes on, and starts to install. But then

```
ERROR bootstrap failed: waited for 10m0s without being able to connect: ssh: connect to host 1xx.xx.xx.20 port 22: Connection timed out
Stopping instance...
Bootstrap failed, destroying environment
```

Using mass, juju on pure metal. No VM.

Comment: Is the host ssh port open and listening?

Answer (score 5):

Consider a higher time-out.

```
    bootstrap-timeout: 1800
```

In your `environments.yaml` should work.

Comment: The value you specify is in seconds. Take a look at `juju help bootstrap` for more information.

Comment: Yes, but what if you've already bootstrapped?  By this point, "juju get-env" indicates that it's still using the prior value (600) for bootstrap-timeout.  In fact, even if you also edit .juju/environments/YOURCLOUDNAME.jenv with this line it still doesn't update the value in the Juju environment.  And you can't edit it with "juju set-env" or it will give an error.  I've been trying to do this and it simply won't adhere to this change.  The /var/log/maas/maas.log indicates that "Starting monitor..." has a timeout of 1200 (which isn't even the 600 that is set.)

Answer (score 1):

Change the timeout value in:

```
/usr/share/openstack/templates/juju-env/maas.yaml
```